# Animate on scroll blinking in mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, jquery-animate, mobile-chrome

I am trying to add animation on scroll in my webite [here](https://msreenivasan.com). I used [animate css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css) and [scroll out js](https://github.com/scroll-out/scroll-out/blob/master/dist/scroll-out.js). My javascript is,

```
<script>
 ScrollOut({
  targets: '.aos',
  onShown: function(el) {
    // remove the class
    el.classList.remove("animated", "fadeIn");

    // force reflow
    void el.offsetWidth;

    // re-add the animated cl
    el.classList.add("animated", "fadeIn");
  }
});
</script>
```

I used `<div class="aos animated fadeIn slow"></div>` in page.

Then it works in all dektop broswers and mobile firefox also, but it gives a blinking before animation in mobile chrome only.
I tried to add `style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);"` to div element, but not working.

Comment: Any fix please...